# Sandbox entitlements for embedded binaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-signing, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

Well, the title is pretty self-explanatory.

- I have an app which validates fine (for the Mac App Store)
- Once I embed a binary in its resources, it compiles/runs fine and codesigning works fine, as long as it is with a Developer ID (outside MAS)
- When I'm trying to validate the app for MAS, I'm getting the following error, stating that App Sandbox not enabled and that it found not entitlements file for the included binary (which is obviously true).

[image]

How can I solve that? Any ideas?

---

**P.S.** Just found this [great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856864/how-can-i-code-sign-a-bundled-executable-file-in-a-mac-app-using-xcode5) and trying it out - I'll let you know how it went!