# How can I run an embedded binary in my OSX application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an application which needs to run an external program.

I have included this program as an `Embedded Framework`.  When archived, it appears at the location `%AppRoot%/Contents/Frameworks/MyExternalApplication.`

How can I run this program from my app's code without using an absolute path?  I'd like to run in both release and debug.

Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

You can run the executable by using an [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) object or the [`posix_spawn()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html) function.

You can use the [`NSBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/) class to find the absolute path of the executable.  See [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html) for details.

Notes:

1. That is not the correct place within the app bundle to place the executable; I believe it should be in `Contents/MacOS`, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19).
2. If the main app is *sandboxed* (a requirement if you want to put the app on the Mac App Store) then an entitlement is required that will be embedded into the external executable so that *it* inherits the app's sandbox.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856864/how-can-i-code-sign-a-bundled-executable-file-in-a-mac-app-using-xcode5) for details.
3. Once you've done 2. you will notice that the executable will no longer run from the command line, but that's nothing to worry about, as it will run from within your app.